# How to recognize rendered components of the same type in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I have a component called clock.component.ts and a dashboard in which I call the clock several times.
In the control dashboard call the runners assigned to the user from the database, if he has 3 assigned runners then he will render the clock.component 3 times. How can I recognize or send the id of each corridor to its respective component?

This is in dashboard.component.html

```
<app-clock *ngFor="let corredor of runnerList"></app-clock>
```

The list runnerList has the object of a runner and there is its id

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-clock',
    templateUrl: './clock.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./clock.component.css']
})

export class ClockComponent implements OnInit {

    idCorredor; //This is the id that I need

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {

    }


    startClock(){
    }

}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way by adding and input to your component.

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-clock',
templateUrl: './clock.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./clock.component.css']
})

export class ClockComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() idCorredor; //This is the id that I need

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {

}


startClock(){
}

}
```

And assign the input this way

```
<app-clock *ngFor="let corredor of runnerList" [idCorredor]="corredor.id"></app-clock>
```